# PHP mysql data vs js dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic

I have a piece of code (in a .php file) that can dynamically add/remove a group of input fields by JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--  ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75408002/javascript-dynamically-add-and-remove-input-fields -->
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
        #template #template_p{ display: none }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <fieldset id="fieldset">
            <legend id="legend">Professional development</legend>
            <div id="placeholder">
                <div id="template">
                    <fieldset id="template_fieldset">
                        <legend>Group</legend>
                        <p>Item <input type ="text" name="prof_item[]" /><br /></p>
                        <p>Duration <input type ="text" name="prof_duration[]" /><br /></p>
                        <p id="template_p"><button type ="button" name="prof_remove[]"  onclick="this.closest('div').remove()">Remove group</button><br /></p>
                    </fieldset>
                </div> <!-- template -->
            </div> <!-- placeholder -->
            <p><button type="button" name="add" onclick="Add();">Add new group</button></p>
        </fieldset>


        <p><button type="submit" name="Submit">Submit</button></p>
    </form>

    <script>
        var _counter = 0;
        function Add() {
            _counter++;
            var oClone = document.getElementById("template").cloneNode(true);
            oClone.id += (_counter + "");
            document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(oClone);
        }        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Using this and adding some PHP code, user data can be collected and saved into MySQL. When the user comes back, is it possible to add the ability to populate the loaded user data into the page, and the user can still dynamically add/remove a group of input fields? I understand that PHP is run on the server and JavaScript is on the client side.

Comment: So your question is? The code you currently have is pure javascript code, nothing of PHP. You will need to have PHP code that does the saving and retrieval of data from and to the mysql database (which then would run on the server side).

Comment: With the above you will be generating duplicate IDs which is not valid. It is not clear what you mean by `"When the user comes back, is it possible to add the ability to populate the loaded user data into the page, and the user can still dynamically add/remove a group of input fields"` - can you clarify please?!

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius If the user has input information already, and the data has been saved into a database, when the user wants to modify/add/remove part of the information, we need to show the user data retrieved from the database and let the user modify/add/remove information.

Comment: I think this question has been sufficiently answered in these comments. Yes, it is clearly possible with PHP. Just retrieve the data rows from the database and generate as many "templates" with these rows in them as needed. Are you satisfied with these answers? You do indeed have a problem with duplicated IDs.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Hmmm, generating more "templates" should be the way to go. Both you and ProfessorAbronsius mentioned about duplicated IDs. ID "template_fieldset" is in fact not used. But I think I ID "template_p" is not causing me problems so far, and when I use PHP to generate multiple "templates", I will skip this ID except the first one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, your code will probably work, even with the duplicated IDs, because you don't actively use them. Read the answers here: [How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really) Remember, when communicating with other programmers about code, you should try to show valid code, that preempts any possible discussion about that.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I should have been more careful. Thanks.